# Fresh install of VS 2015 and i'm getting "Unable to launch the IIS Express Web Server"

Tags: visual-studio, iis, iis-express

So I just reset my PC and reinstalled VS, however the project I was working on was working fine before but now when I try to launch it I get the error as below, without any more output in any windows I know of.

[image]

I tried making a new project and launching it which worked perfectly fine, without error. I don't understand why I'm getting this error or how to troubleshoot it, most similar cases I've seen are people getting a "Port already in use error" which I tried changing the port just in case but with no change

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37991669/unable-to-launch-the-iis-web-server-how-to-debug identical problem to mine, did you fix it?

Comment: @tallpaul Sorry I havn't had any luck with it either, moved away from that project since then i'll probably have another look at it once .NET Core is at RTM