# Unable to launch the IIS Web Server, how to debug

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, iis, visual-studio-2015

I am having problems with my IIS Express in Visual Studio Pro 2015. When I try and start a website I get an error with the single line

[image]

The project is one that I have written but have reloaded from TFS after my HDD was scrapped. The same error occurs if I create a new project.

I am using the `applicationhost.config` file stored in `project\.vs\config`

I have tried the following:

- Deleted `%project%\.vs\config` and `C:\Users\Paul\Documents\IISExpress\` and let VS rebuild it
- Temporarily changed the bindings in `applicationhost.config` manually to include `*` and `https`
- Changed the port number in `Preferences -> Web -> Project Url`
- Looked for conflicting ports in `TCPView` (trying to run from VS doesn't appear here as it doesn't get that far)
- Toggled .Net in `Turn Windows features on or off`
- Uninstalled IIS and re-installed
- Uninstalled VS and re-installed
- Cleaned and rebuilt solution
- Restarted many times

If I run `C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\iisexpress.exe /config:%project%\.vs\config\applicationhost.config /site:Name /siteid:2 /systray:true /trace:error` there are no errors and IIS starts as expected.

**The only obvious difference between this installation and the last is that I now have IISExpress on C: drive and VS on D: **

I only have the following software installed on this PC:
Visual Studio Pro 2015,
Xamarin Studio 6,
Android Studio, and
SQL Server Express 2014.
OS is Windows 10 Pro.

I understand that the error is very generic, can anyone advise how I debug what the actual fault is?

**EDIT:** I'm checking through the details at https://blog.lextudio.com/2015/11/jexus-manager-secrets-behind-visual-studio-iis-express-integration/

My `csproj` file appears to be missing many of the IIS related tags in that page, I added them for chance but it still fails:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="14.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <UseIISExpress>true</UseIISExpress>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ProjectExtensions>
    <VisualStudio>
      <FlavorProperties GUID="{349c5851-65df-11da-9384-00065b846f21}">
        <WebProjectProperties>
          <StartPageUrl>
          </StartPageUrl>
          <StartAction>CurrentPage</StartAction>
          <AspNetDebugging>True</AspNetDebugging>
          <SilverlightDebugging>False</SilverlightDebugging>
          <NativeDebugging>False</NativeDebugging>
          <SQLDebugging>False</SQLDebugging>
          <ExternalProgram>
          </ExternalProgram>
          <StartExternalURL>
          </StartExternalURL>
          <StartCmdLineArguments>
          </StartCmdLineArguments>
          <StartWorkingDirectory>
          </StartWorkingDirectory>
          <EnableENC>True</EnableENC>
          <AlwaysStartWebServerOnDebug>True</AlwaysStartWebServerOnDebug>
        </WebProjectProperties>
      </FlavorProperties>
    </VisualStudio>
  </ProjectExtensions>
</Project>
```

**EDIT:** [This dev has the same problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37670022/fresh-install-of-vs-2015-and-im-getting-unable-to-launch-the-iis-express-web-s)

Comment: Anything to do with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14660366/unable-to-launch-web-server/14660479#14660479 ?

Comment: https://blog.lextudio.com/2015/11/jexus-manager-secrets-behind-visual-studio-iis-express-integration/ check your project file please.

Comment: thanks, I will do, I've set VS installation to repair ant I'll check when it's back

Comment: @LexLi I'm going through your link this morning, I don't have `<IISExpressSSLPort />
<IISExpressAnonymousAuthentication />
<IISExpressWindowsAuthentication />
<IISExpressUseClassicPipelineMode />
<UseGlobalApplicationHostFile />` or most of the parts following `<UseIIS>True</UseIIS>` in my`csproj` file, are they there by default?

Comment: see this question http://stackoverflow.com/a/35799805/4794648 see this question http://stackoverflow.com/a/35799805/4794648

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uninstalled VS & IIS, then followed the advice [here to completely burn VS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33138106) by using [this Microsoft tool](https://github.com/Microsoft/VisualStudioUninstaller/releases).

Reinstalled VS and it's working.

Thanks all.